# Clicking on a Button in Webbrowser with only a class

Tags: javascript, html

So i've seen alot of clicking by button but i haven't seen a click by class yet. Can someone help me here is the HTML Button code

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_2273468();
<span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Like</div></a>
```

Please help me out really need this. Thanks :D

Comment: $('.single_like_button').on('click', function(){ $('form').submit() })

Comment: Doesn't understand $('.single_like_button').on('click', function(){ $('form').submit() })  Please right it in full form i'm kinda new to this

Comment: There is something called Jquery, have a glace at http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: You seem to be  using inline event handlers, then why does `class`  matter?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for that. Once you add jQuery reference to your HTML's `head` like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

...then you can do something like this in your `head`'s `<script>` block:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    $('.single_like_button').click(function(){
        //you can use $(this) to reference the calling object, <a> in this case 
        //$(this).css('color','red'); 
        openFbLWin_2273468();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this in C#?

Comment: @KodyN.Voyles I've seen your other question as well. You really need to understand the difference between client side and server side.